# Find the path between a node to another given node in a tree represented by an adjacency list

Tags: java, python, c++, tree, adjacency-list

Find the path between a node to another given node in a ***Tree*** represented by an ***Adjacency List***
EDIT:
The tree is given as an acyclic connected graph of n nodes where nodes are from 1 to n
For example if when n = 5 the tree is given as:
1 4
4 5
3 2
4 2
I should be able to find the path between any of the n nodes using the algorithm
I can program in c++ and java and python

Comment: Do you expect people to do your homework? Write the code, do whatever you can, and if you need specific help, post the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either via BFS or DFS. It will take O(N) time. However if you want to query for any 2 of N nodes than it can be done online using Heavy Light Decomposition.

Here is a BFS based implementation.

```
int n;
cin >> n;
vector <int> graph[n], visited(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
{
    int st, en;
    cin >> st >> en;
    st--;
    en--;
    graph[st].push_back(en);
    graph[en].push_back(st);
}
int st, en;
cin >> st >> en;
st--, en--;
queue  <pair <int, int> > q;
q.push({st, 0});
visited[st] = 1;
while (!q.empty())
{
    auto  top = q.front();
    if (top.first == en)
        return top.second;
    q.pop();
    for (auto & x : graph[top.first])
    {
        if(!visited[x])
        {
            q.push({x, top.second + 1});
            visited[x] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't return the path but i modified it to make it work .Thanks . I used a similar dfs approach earlier but it didn't work for all cases . Any idea why ?

Comment: You can use mapping between parent and child node to get path.
Here you can find my similar solution to your problem. Can you share link to the problem and your code.

https://pastebin.com/HuiYsH7t

Answer (score 0):

First take a visited array and initialize it with 0 for all the nodes.
Mark the start node (s) in the visited array as 1(i.e. visited) and perform a basic DFS on this node. As soon as you arrive on the desired node, stop the algorithm.
DFS:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/

Answer (score -1):

You should look up **dijkstra's** and **A*** path finding algorithms, they will solve this for you if your data can be manipulated.

**dijkstra's** is my favorite, simple to understand. But not as efficient as **A***
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Can't really give a more useful answer without knowing how your data is stored, what programming language or graphing software you're using, please add tags and be more descriptive in your question.

Hope this helps.